# QAbstractProxyModel not updating on dataChanged() signal

Tags: c++, qt

Here is my `setData` in source model:

```
bool TreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role)
{
    if (!index.isValid() || role != Qt::EditRole)
        return false;

    TreeItem* item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    item->setData(index.column(), value);
    emit dataChanged(index, index);

    return true;
}
```

I connected `dataChanged` signal from source model to `dataChanged` signal of proxy model but the table view which shows proxy model updates only if I click on it. What can be wrong in this situation? Should I somehow emit `dataChanged` signal manually in proxy model?

Data from model:

```
QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid() || role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return {};

    TreeItem* item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    return item->dataAt(index.column());
}
```

And from TreeItem:

```
QVariant TreeItem::dataAt(int n) const
{
    if (n < m_data.size())
        return m_data[n];
    else
        return {};
}
```

Update:
I supposed that proxy model should use `mapFromSource` on indices that came from `TreeModel::dataChanged` but it seems proxy doesn't call `mapFromSource`, so I don't understand how updating happens.

Also the same behaviour when I try to edit tree item through proxy model - source model doesn't update it's view. However in that case I can set data in proxy using source model:

```
bool ProxyModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role)
{
//    if (!index.isValid() || role != Qt::EditRole)
//        return false;

//    TreeItem* item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(mapToSource(index).internalPointer());
//    item->setData(index.column(), value);
//    emit dataChanged(index, index);

//    return true;

    return sourceModel()->setData(mapToSource(index), value, role);
}
```

UPDATE:
Finally, it seems that I'm almost got it. KDE's KDescendantsProxyModel model emitting `dataChanged` signal itself, so I also created `onSourceDataChanged` slot and connected it to source's `dataChanged` signal (it updates only first index now):

```
void ProxyModel::onSourceDataChanged(const QModelIndex& topLeft, const QModelIndex& bottomRight,
                                     const QVector<int>& roleNames)
{
    auto index = mapFromSource(topLeft);
    emit dataChanged(index, index);
}
```

The only question: is it a right way or I do something wrong?

Comment: Possible, problem is in your `item->setData`. Please show a code of your `TreeModel::data` and `TreeItem::setData` methods. Btw, to write more clear code, don't forget to use `emit` macro: `emit dataChanged(index, index);`.

Comment: I emit dataChanged signal in TreeModel::setData() method. And tree view that shows TreeModel is updating as expected.

Comment: Unfortunalety, I don't know what the problem is. Btw, if you access `index.internalPointer()` inside your proxy model, it will be invalid. You need to access to internal pointers directly in source model indexes.

Comment: I think it's depend on how index was created. If I create index in proxy as createIndex(row, column, s.internalPointer()), where 's' is index of source model - proxy's index will contain valid pointer.

Comment: Only if you are creating indexes in proxy by yourelf. Because I got similar problems in my projects.

Comment: Yes. If I understand it correctly, proxy model has not it's own items, therefore it cannot provide pointers to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I connected `dataChanged` signal from source model to `dataChanged` signal of proxy mode

You cannot re-emit the source model's signal, as that signal has the index to a wrong model. Remember `dataChanged`'s contract: the index it emits is a valid index on the model the signal comes from. Yet you're emitting an index that's not valid on your proxy model.

You need to connect the source's signal to a slot or functor that then maps the index to the proxy's index and emits that.

Comment: Yes, I updated my post. I wish you answer a few hours early)